# For loop not showing the count value in UIlable

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am new to ios developement. When I loop through, for example, 3000, I want show the each value in `UILabel`. But it is showing the last count value after the loop ends. here is simple code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
    myLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", i];
    NSLog(@"loop is running");
}
NSLog(@"loop is finished");
```

I also used GCD but no result.

The above code is just an example .In for loop what i want is

I want to add the 3000 or more contacts when the user select the group of contacts .if any contact is added i want to show the count value in uilable. Something like this

```
-(void)addContacts:(NSArray*)numberOfContacts
{    
   for (int i = 0; i < [numberOfContacts count]; i++) {
  //method call to add the contact ex:[self addContact:@"murali" phoneNumber:@"41524652"]
    myLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", i];

   }
}
```

Comment: So, the label will take each value in 0..3000, but because you're overwriting it each time, you'll only ever see the last value (it's too fast to view). What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: append string don't overwrite in for loop.

Comment: or is it that you want to display these values serially ? in that case you should implement a timer.

Comment: The loop will execute too fast for you to actually see it. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: even that overwrites,i want that overwritten value.here the thing is ui is blocking.if i give one initial value in uilable that will be there until the loop finishes. after loop ends the last value i.e 2999 is placed in uilable.means here any atleast value by value overwritting is not hapening.please execute in your xcode.and see the result

Comment: here my problem is i want to add the 3000 or more contacts .if any contact is added i want to show the count value in uilable.here if i want some delay i need to use timer .i dont want delay .

Comment: It is, because redrawing is done via the run loop. but you never return to the run loop. (To be honest: You do that when the whole loop is done.) You cannot d this this way in an event driven application.

Comment: solution please.if i place that code in one method and if i call that method 3000 times will it work?

Comment: Generally all the UI components will refresh at once. It means when you do any UI changes in one method, all will be changed at once untill there is no delay. So you can not do it with out delay

Comment: @murali yes, if you return to the run loop meanwhile. I posted a solution.

Comment: but ,is it good programming way to place a calling statement in for loop? and will it take any extra processor time?

Comment: adding a "calling" statement would change anything, because that does not *return* to the run loop.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad ,i didn't get your point .want i understood from your last comment is "it may take extra processor time". i am also thinking in performance way also.

Comment: If doing something 3000 times takes a short time, you shouldn't update a label. If it takes time, you don't need to care about "calls".

Comment: i agree.but in your posted answer you said that " you can dispatch a redraw block to the main queue" .how to dispatch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that this way. Screen refreshing is done via run loop that means, after your event handling method is completly done. If you do "3.000 things" in the method, the screen will update afterwards. You should understand run loops. It is a core competence.

I do not know, what you want to do exactly. The typical approach to do such a thing is different:

You do it in background, i. e. using GCD. In the background block you can dispatch a redraw block to the main queue.

Comment: how to dispatch from background to main queque  using for loop     dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(
                                                       DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    
            for (int i=0; i<3000; i++) {
                
                
            }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

      
        });
    });

Comment: Seems to be the right way on a first (unformatted) view.

Comment: any way i understood one thing that "only control enters into runloop at that time only ui is refreshed".right. thanks for your valuable info.